Prevent blank padding in query response from a char type column in oracle
I have a table in Oracle Database that its column type is char(100).



ID
VALUE




1
Test



In insertion the 'Test' value is blank padded by oracle.
When I select this row from the database I must trim it to get the non-padded value.
select trim(value) from mytable where id = 1
It does not make sense cause it is not the actual inserted value. Is there any solution to get the actual non-padded value without using trim or changing the column type to varchar ?

Yea, for strings use varchar2 always. There's almost no situation where char is better.  It's pretty much a holdover from the fixed-width flat file days. I only ever use char for 1-byte flags (e.g., Y, N) guaranteed to never be any other size, but even then the space savings from having to have a size byte is miniscule.

This question appears to be asking: "I am using a data-type that automatically pads values to the fill the entire length of the data-type; how can I get it to stop padding the value?" And surely the answer is to not use that data-type! Why do you state that you don't want to change to using VARCHAR2 (which VARCHAR is an alias of), when that is what would solve your problem?

When using varchar2(100) oracle takes the disk space based on the current value, e.g., 'abc' would approximately takes 4 bytes. When the column value is updated to something else like 'abcabc' which needs 7 spaces. The value cannot be hold on the precious allocated disk block and it causes disk fragmentation.

@SinaAskarnejad - That seems like a separate question.  Updates may potentially cause row migration.  In the vast majority of systems, having row migration is not something that causes any problems.  Have you measured some sort of performance problem in your particular system?  If that is actually a problem, normally you'd just set the pctfree to reserve more space in the block for future updates based on the expected lifecycle of data.

Thanks @JustinCave. Using varchar2 with pctfree will mitigate the problem.

The short answer is "no" there isn't a way to do this. The CHAR datatype automatically pads the value you insert to the full size of the column. In my experience, CHAR is rarely used because it takes up disk space and inflates storage requirements, even for empty values. If you want only your data to be stored without padding, you must use VARCHAR2.
See here: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-char/

When you insert or update a fixed-length character string column,
Oracle stores the characters as the fixed-length data.
It means that if you store a value whose length is less than the
maximum length defined in the column, Oracle pads the spaces to the
character string up to the maximum length.


As far as I know, varchar2 causes disk fragmentation on updates. consider the following situation: When using varchar2(100) oracle takes the disk space based on the current value, e.g., 'abc' would approximately takes 4 bytes. When the column value is updated to something else like 'abcabc' which needs 7 spaces. The value cannot be hold on the previous allocated disk block and it causes disk fragmentation.

Using varchar2 by considering pctfree has mitigated the issue.
